# What is the ORM version in Sequelize referring to?

Tags: node.js, npm, sequelize.js

I have two servers and I am trying to get their versions to match. when I run `sequelize --version` I get the below outputs:

Server 1: `Sequelize CLI [Node: 14.18.0, CLI: 5.5.1, ORM: 6.21.3]`
`5.5.1`

Server 2: `Sequelize CLI [Node: 14.18.0, CLI: 5.5.1, ORM: 5.19.0]`
`5.5.1`

I can see they both have the same Sequelize version (5.5.1) but have different ORM versions. In this context what is the ORM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `5.5.1` is not the sequelize version it is the "sequelize CLI" version, "ORM: 5.19.0" is in fact the actual sequelize version.